# Google Analytics events while user is offline (mobile)

Tags: google-analytics

Mixpanel, Localytics and so on record events even when the user is off wifi and send it over when he comes back again. I couldn't find much detail if Google Analytics is able to do that. So is it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

The Google Analytics Measurement Protocol allows developers to make HTTP requests to send raw user interaction data directly to Google Analytics servers. This allows developers to measure how users interact with their business from almost any environment. Developers can then use the Measurement Protocol to:

- Measure user activity in new environments.
- Tie online to offline behavior.
- Send data from both the web and server.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/

More specifically there is a parameter called [queue time](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt) - you can send an offset between the time when an event occured and the time is was sent to the server.

Comment: So basically it's on the developers end to take care of the offline behaviour?

Comment: Yes you are going to have to have a developer take care of this for you.

Comment: There's a library Google has made for dealing with this, based on a service worker detecting failed requests: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/modules/workbox-google-analytics/ (I have not tried it myself).